# Is this normal? Am seeing SAME exit/ entry nodes from same 2-3 countries all the time! :(

Tags: torsocks

To my knowledge there are hundreds of Tor entry/exit nodes. But during a 4-5 hour browsing I am only seeing nodes from France (a lot), Germany and the Netherlands.

Why am i not seeing any nodes from places like Brazil, other european countries, Asia or South America?

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Entry guards are expected to be the same over a long time period. Take a look at [proposal 236](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/236-single-guard-node.txt) for the reasoning behind it.

The reason that you see so many relays from France, Germany and Netherlands is that they have by far the most nodes. Take a look at the bubble graph showing [all relays by country](https://metrics.torproject.org/bubbles.html#country) or the one showing [exit nodes only](https://metrics.torproject.org/bubbles.html#country-exits-only).

We all wish the distribution was different, but it is up to the volunteers running the nodes to decide where they want to run them. And of course, in some countries you can't run a node at all for legal reasons.